# Why are these triggers not detecting wrong data although the syntax should be correct?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I want to add two triggers to my mysql database, but it seems that both triggers are not working (although the mysql compiler accepts the syntax). I do not receive an error message when I insert new data rows that should be detected as wrong by the trigger. Do you know what the mistake could be?

Here is the code of the triggers:

```
USE `mydb`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Teilnehmer_BEFORE_INSERT` $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`Teilnehmer_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Teilnehmer` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),NEW.Geburtsdatum) < 6570) THEN

        -- Throw Exception
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Age is less than 18 years!';
        END IF;  -- A semicolon (delimiter) is missing here
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `enforce_phone_check` BEFORE INSERT ON `Teilnehmer` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.Telefonnummer REGEXP '^(\\+?[0-9]{1,4}-)?[0-9]{3,10}$' ) = 0 THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '33455'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Your Phone Number is incorrect';
   END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Preis` (
  `idPreis` INT NOT NULL,
  `Menge` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Wert` INT NULL,
  `Art` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPreis`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Teilnehmer` (
  `idTeilnehmer` INT NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Preis_idPreis` INT NOT NULL,
  `Vorname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Nachname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Strasse` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Hausnr.` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `PLZ` INT(4) NULL,
  `Ort` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `Geburtsdatum` DATE NULL,
  `Telefonnummer` VARCHAR(16) NULL,
  `Bild_URL TEXT` TEXT(500) NULL,
  `ts` timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTeilnehmer`, `Preis_idPreis`),
  INDEX `fk_Teilnehmer_Preis1_idx` (`Preis_idPreis` ASC)   VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Teilnehmer_Preis1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Preis_idPreis`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Preis` (`idPreis`),
  UNIQUE Key `idTeilnehmer`(`idTeilnehmer`, `Nachname`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And here is a table entry that should throw an error for both trigger (but doesn't):

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`teilnehmer` (`idTeilnehmer`, `email`, `Preis_idPreis`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `Strasse`, `Hausnr.`, `PLZ`, `Ort`, `Geburtsdatum`, `Telefonnummer`, `Bild_URL TEXT`, `ts`) VALUES ('1', 'sdfsdf', '1', 'sdfsd', 'sdfsd', 'sdfsdf', '17', '9230', 'Flawil', '2005-06-06', '2342345', 'stsdfsdf', '2019-06-06');
```

Comment: FWIW, I think a presentation layer is the correct place to do data validation.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, triggers work as expected.Please add table definitions and insert statements which you think should generate errors

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon , I've included the information

Comment: You do know that second trigger will not fire if first detects an error? And why have 2 triggers on the same table? Code is working as expected..

Comment: Check if the triggers were actually created (`show triggers like '%Teilnehmer%'`), and check if the row was inserted or not.